# How to change Default libtool on MacOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

When I type  'which libtool' on Mac OSX Yosemite
I get this

/opt/local/bin/libtool

I think I don't want this. I need the Xcode one to be default. Is this in 
/usr/bin

How do I change the default tools from /opt/local/bin to /usr/bin

When I installed Xcode 6 command line tools I assumed that these would be default
so something has gone wrong somewhere

Thanks

Comment: check the content of your `~/.bash_profile` file - there is probably a `PATH=` setting `/opt/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`; probably placed there by `macports`

Comment: Ok thanks, I removed that and now it seems right. Does this mean one cannot have macports installed along with xcode

Comment: Your `.bash_profile` file should not interfere with xcode as the default path on OSX does not contain `/opt/local/bin`. Only terminal window builds would be affected by this.